# Best Approach for an Event Calendar in PHP/MySQL

Tags: mysql, database, datetime, calendar

I'm working on an event calendar, using MySQL and PHP.

I already set up a table with the dates and hours and the calendar works pretty well. I have to make an event calendar for multiple rooms, so I was thinking I would have to create a table for every new room that is added to the DB.

Considering my calendar is divided by intervals of half and hour, my index column goes like this: `2010-1-1 00:00:00`, `2010-1-1 00:30:00`, `2010-1-1 01:00:00` and so on, for about 25 years into the future. Also there's another column with the event ID.

I think it would take too much time, as well as space, everytime I add a room, because a new HUGE table would have to be created. Is there a simpler approach for this?

Comment: Do events fit into 1 30 minute interval or do they span multiple intervals?

Comment: They can fit in multiple 30 minutes intervals, for example, if I add and event that lasts 3 hours, it would take 5 rows.
eg.
00:00:00 -
00:30:00 -
01:00:00 -
01:30:00 -
02:00:00 -
02:30:00.

Comment: I think this approach is very cumbersome. Why not just create a start/end date time stamp for an event? You can query for and place events in their proper day, while rendering the rest of the calendar blank. Why is there a need for generating intervals ahead of time?

Comment: Room can have multiple events, event will have a event_id, room_id, title, start_date, end_date, etc. You can pull all events for 1 room with one query, group them by days if you have to, etc.

Comment: Yeah, the thinkg with that, is that I got to check if the "room" is busy, on those dates, so events do not overlap between them , I got your idea, I'm not very experienced in DB. So, if you have a suggestion to this. I would be happy to read it.

Comment: if you're going to be adding rooms as time goes on, it will be difficult to maintain adding a new table for every room. Have you considered creating a Rooms table to which you can add a new *row* every time a room is added?

Comment: There is a table for Rooms, it has all the information about them, and , from the start, I tought this was kinda messy, but it was working for me, so I just stuck to it, until I found out the time it took to create that huge calendar table. Now its clearer for me, thanks for your comments.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you create an event table containing following:

```
event_id, room_id, title, start_date(datetime), end_date(datetime)
```

You can then check if the room 1 is occupied for between 11:30AM and 1:30PM range with this:

```
select count(event_id) from events where room_id = 1 and ((end_date > '2012-10-02 11:30:00')
AND (start_date < '2012-10-02 13:30:00'));
```

Anything greater than 0 indicates existing events in room 1 for this datetime range. Or you can return conflicting event and show it to the user by select `*` instead of `count(event_id)`

Comment: Yep, but , what if I have multiple events on the same day, at different times, like Room 1: Event 1 from 1 PM to 3 PM , then Event 2 from 4 PM to 6 PM. 
I'm thinking, I should compare at date_time level, to acomplish this, I'm not quite sure, but I will definetely try this.

Comment: Right, start date, and end date, are date time, it will work either way. I just called them date, I will update my answer.

Comment: Well, I will try this, I'll be back on Monday, to tell you my results.
Thanks a lot.